# How to use log4j to save the output to a file

Tags: java, servlets, jar

I have downloaded the log4j jar.
But dont know how to use it to save the output to a text file.
My code is:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Enumeration;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class ShowHeaders extends HttpServlet {

  /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
String headerName;
String headerValue;

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
      response.setContentType("text/plain");
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

      String method= request.getMethod();
      out.println("Request Method: " +method);
      out.println("-----------------------");
      String uri= request.getRequestURI();
      out.println("URI: " +uri);
      out.println("-----------------------");


      out.println("Request Headers");

      Enumeration<?> Enumeration = (java.util.Enumeration<?>) request.getHeaderNames();
      while (Enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
      String headerName = (String) Enumeration.nextElement();
      String headerValue = request.getHeader(headerName);
      out.print(""+headerName + ": ");
      out.println(headerValue + "");

     }

}
```

Kindly tell me where to describe the file location & what to use instead of out.println(); to display it that text file

Comment: What? Did you mean `log4j`? Did you bother to read the manual?

Comment: i am sorry, you are correct its log4j. I have read the documentation manual but i am totally confused on how to use it.

Comment: This tutorial seems good : http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html have you read it already ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should take a look at the [log4j tutorial](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html). It is really good !

this code should give you a headstart :

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Logger X = Logger.getLogger("com.foo");
    try {
        X.addAppender(new FileAppender(new PatternLayout("%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n"),"src/test.log"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    X.debug("Hello World debug message");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The log4j [tutorial](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/manual.html) explains how to configure logging, and includes example configs that log to a file.  (Search for where it says "Here is another configuration file that uses multiple appenders".  That "config" includes file appenders.)